# How to check if a categoryID exists in a theme options page

Tags: categories, theme-options

I have tried to make a theme options page (starting with a sample theme options page from themeshaper) and I want to check if a comma separated list of categories is valid. Remove duplicates, remove non-existing categories, but it doesn't work. :(

It is deleting the last value if I check with empty():

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
    if ($input['slidercats'] != '') {  
        $slidercats = $input['slidercats'];
        $slidercats_array = explode( ',', $slidercats );
        $slidercats_array = array_unique( $slidercats_array );
        $slidercats_array = array_map('intval', $slidercats_array );

        foreach($slidercats_array AS $i => $value)  
        {  
            $cat = get_category($i); // cat_ID
            if ( empty( $cat ) )
                unset($slidercats_array[$i]);
        }  

        $input['slidercats'] = implode(",", $slidercats_array);     

    }

    return $input;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/xR1aq6mD

And it is deleting all values but one with `term_exists(id, 'category');`

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
    // global $select_options, $radio_options;

    // Change to integer
    $input['slidercount'] = (int)$input['slidercount'];
    if ($input['slidercount'] < 1 || $input['slidercount'] > 50)
        $input['slidercount'] = 10;

    // Make array from string, remove duplicates, change all values to integer, remove non existing categories, make string from array
    if ($input['slidercats'] != '') {  
        $slidercats = $input['slidercats'];
        $slidercats_array = explode( ',', $slidercats );
        $slidercats_array = array_unique( $slidercats_array );
        $slidercats_array = array_map('intval', $slidercats_array );

        foreach($slidercats_array AS $i => $value)  
        {  
            $cat = term_exists($i, 'category'); // cat_ID
            if ( ! $cat )
                unset($slidercats_array[$i]);
        } 

        $input['slidercats'] = implode(",", $slidercats_array);     

    }

    return $input;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/edx8F1YZ

The problem is the `foreach`, but I'm stuck and no php guru. Maybe someone could give me a hint how to solve this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, `$i` is not going to be your category ID.

```
 foreach($slidercats_array AS $i => $value)  
    {  
        $cat = get_category($i); // cat_ID
        if ( empty( $cat ) )
            unset($slidercats_array[$i]);
    }
```

At least I don't see how it could be. If you `explode` a string the keys in the resulting array are numerical and sequentially generated starting at 0. I assume that your original string is a comma separated list of category ids. That would mean that the `key`s of the array-- the `$i`s-- are 
going to have no relationship to your category ids. For example:

```
$arr = '9,8,7,6,5,4'; // assume these to be category IDs
print_r(explode(',',$arr));

/* Returns
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 4
) */
```

You want to be using the `$value` not the `$i`. The `$i` is the `[0],[1],[2]`, etc. You want the second half-- the `$value`-- when you check for the category (or term).

```
$cat = get_category($value); // cat_ID
```

You still want the `$i` when you `unset` though.

You seem to be making the same mistake in the second block as well and I am fairly sure that is incorrect use of the array keys is the root of the problem.